# How to call a JS function every 10 sec which then activates a function in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, highcharts

I am trying to use a highcharts chart and I want to "simulate" live data coming in, so, when a user presses the "start live stream" button it activates a function from I suppose JavaScript on the web page and then calls the angular controller function that has around 10 second delay.

The way I can query the json data from the controller is from an http request and I use how far back in weeks I want to query the data (I have as far back as 100 weeks). So I want to have a function on the web page the starts at 99 and 100 and pass in the variable to the angular function to query from 100-99 weeks ago and add the data to the chart. Wait 10 seconds and query now instead 99-98 until it gets to zero.

I am pretty new to JS in general so I'm not too sure how to start but I have read about the setTimeout function. Any suggestions or better way to go about this would be much appreciated.

My current http request looks like this and is static:

```
$http({
           url: '/api/v1/datapoints',
           method: 'POST',    
           data: '{"start":"99w-ago","end":"98w-ago","tags":[{"name":"SolarData"}]}'
         }).then(function(predixTimeSeriesData){
                 $scope.solarData = predixTimeSeriesData.data.tags[0].results[0].values.map(
             function(curVal, index, arr) {
                return [curVal[0], curVal[1]];
                }
                );
        console.log($scope.solarData);
        /*
          I use $scope.solatData in my chart on the html page like
          <line-series-chart data={{solarData}}></line-series-chart>
          so this is why I am thinking I need to have the time interval on the view page 
          instead of the controller because i cannot control my chart from there
        */

        });
```

Comment: Use the [`$interval`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval) and/or [`$timeout`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout) service of angular

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `$interval` service of angular, something like this:

```
function myController($scope, $http, $interval) {

    var currentWeek = 99;
    var fetchInterval;

    $scope.solatData = [];

    $scope.fetch = function() {
        $http.get("someUrl", {
            params: {
                week: currentWeek
            }
        }).then(function(data){
            // This will also update your graph, assuming it is implemented
            // to watch changes on the data
            $scope.solatData = $scope.solatData.concat(data);
            currentWeek++;
        });
    }

    $scope.start = function() {
        fetchInterval = $interval($scope.fetch, 10000);
    }

    // Clear the interval when the scope/controller is 'destroyed'
    $scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
        $interval.cancel(fetchInterval);
    });

    // kick off initial start
    $scope.start();
}
```

Comment: Do i have to call the function through the html page as well? It currently is not working.

Comment: You have to kick of the interval, with `$scope.start()`